# Optimize 'Not In' Query for NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql, scalability, query-performance

For my application when pulling documents from my NoSQL database, I need to ensure that they are unique documents every time and not ones that I've already pulled.

**Two approaches I have considered:**

1) A basic Not-In/'$nin' query that checks the potential documents against a given local array of document ID's that have already been pulled (gets updated on every pull as well).

2) Instead of using a NIN condition in the query, after pulling potential documents I then manually sift out documents that match the DocID's in a locally constructed hash map (gets updated on every pull as well).

Both of these approaches seem slightly inefficient, so I was wondering if there was a more optimized solution that I have not thought about yet?

Comment: The first option to use and run a query on the database with `$nin` operator can be efficient - if you have an index on the query filter field. You can check by generating a _query plan_ with `explain` method. The second option of manually sifting is not recommended when you can run the query directly on the database server (the first option).

Comment: Does this mean that pulling docs with `$nin` is not n^2? The way I understand it is that the array I am passing into the query is not 'indexed' (aka not a hash-map), so for each doc pulled we would have to iterate through the given array to check if it's in it => n*n = n^2 ?

Comment: You will be indexing the field of your collection. The array you will be passing will be an array - see [$nin documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/index.html).

Comment: I just read the docs, and in my case I will be using the auto-created index on the Document ID, however, since `$nin` still needs to iterate over every document, I am failing to see how this is any more efficient than n^2?

Also in regards to your initial comment, the documentation states that: "...in many cases, a $nin query with an index may perform no better than a $nin query that must scan all documents in a collection. "

Comment: If you are matching against the autogenerated _id, and are not skipping around in the collection, you could use `$gt` to fetch documents after the latest one you've seen.